# Insert datetime to database using json_populate_record

Tags: python, json, postgresql

How can I insert python's `datetime` to timestamp column using using `json_populate_record`?

I tried an [advice][1]. But it doesn't work for me, when I'm using `json_populate_record`:

```
def add_trade(self, order_sell_id: UUID, execution_time: datetime):
    trade = {
        "order_sell_id": order_sell_id,
        "execution_time": "TIMESTAMP " + str(execution_time)
    }
    try:
        order_sql = (
            f"INSERT INTO \"trade\"(order_sell_id, execution_time) "
            f" SELECT order_sell_id, execution_time"
            f" FROM "
            f"json_populate_record(NULL::\"trade\", '{json.dumps(trade)}');")

        result = self.database.query(order_sql)
    except pg.IntegrityError as e:
        pass
```

For the code above I have an exception:

```
pg.DataError: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "TIMESTAMP 2018-06-15 16:14:36"
```

I tried insert `datetime` by just adding to dict:

```
"execution_time": execution_time
```

And got:

```
pg.DataError: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "1529069127000"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use just `str()`:

```
    "execution_time": str(execution_time)
```

or format the datetime with `strftime()`:

```
    "execution_time": execution_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```